# Bracket error in c "error: expected identifier or '(' {"

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on a problem set for CS50 in C but I keep getting an error `readability.c:11:1: error: expected identifier or '(' {` and I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letters(string text);

int main(void);
{
    string paragraph = get_string("Input text: ");

    count_letters(paragraph);

    int L = 0;
    int S = 0;

    int index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

    printf("%i", index);
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int letters = 0;

    for (int i = 0, length = strlen(text); i < length; i++)
        if isalpha(text[i]) {
            letters + 1
        }

    return letters;
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon at

```
int main(void);
```

and you need one here:

```
for (int i = 0, length = strlen(text); i < length; i++){ //added {
  if(!(isalpha(text[i]) == 0)){ // is alpha in brackets too and I usually prefer to check result with proper types
    letters + 1; //addded ;
  }
}
```

Comment: `letters + 1;` still does not do anything.